# Set rows visibility using Policy and RLS

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, postgresql-10, row-level-security

I need to hide the rows with `deleted = true` values for all `select` statements to the table.

I thought of using row level security with a `select` policy, but it does not seem to work.

Here's what I tried:

```
alter table my_table force row level security;

create policy my_selection_policy on my_table
for select to public using (deleted is not true);
```

The expected result is that now all `deleted` rows in `my_table` should be automatically filtered out from any select query on `my_table`.

So, basically, the query `select * from my_table where deleted = true;` would return me an empty result.

---

How do I implement such functionality correctly? Is RLS + policy the correct way to implement that? Or should I just use a `before select` trigger?

Comment: What about using a View for this specific query?

Comment: @AbdisamadKhalif I will not have a `specific` query. I'm trying to achieve the default filtering for all select queries on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, basically, the query select * from my_table where deleted = true; would return me an empty result.

Because you don't need to use `where` clause in this case to remove soft-deleted records from your result set.

You just need `select * from my_table;` soft deleted records are already filtered out using `using (deleted is not true);`

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Can you be more specific? Are you talking about using a `view`?

Comment: Use select * from my_table; instead of select * from my_table where deleted = true; then it will not return an empty result.

Comment: But what you're saying doesn't work. `select * from my_table` gives me the exact same result both with and without the policy.

Comment: If you're connected to your database using "postgres" superuser or other superuser, then it gives you "the exact same result both with and without the policy". Connect your db using other non-superuser who has access to that db, and test the query.

Comment: But is there a way to force the policy for superuser as well? I've tried `alter table my_table force row level security;`, but this did not work

Comment: From docs 

"Superusers and roles with the BYPASSRLS attribute always bypass the row security system when accessing a table. Table owners normally bypass row security as well, though a table owner can choose to be subject to row security with ALTER TABLE ... FORCE ROW LEVEL SECURITY."

Comment: But I do try to use `force row level security`. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot ALTER postgres superuser to NOT skip row level security policy.

Comment: Row level security policies do not apply to superusers, in this case, postgres superuser.